# pjsua2(psjip library) on Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, pjsip

I'm trying run **pjsua2**(pjsip library) sample program on my ***Android*** board.I've already done installation by using [this](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android) website

After importing it in eclipse and running I got this exception:

[image: PJSip Android issue]

I'm working on **Ubuntu 14.04 x64** and both *sdk* and *ndk* available.Are there any one exists, who struggled that error or know howto deal with this time killer issue?

Answer (score 0):

I think this happened because of android architecture conflict.You must run the application in a device that support the architecture you build. I also build using [this link](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android) and it worked for me.But i build pjsip using this code:

```
TARGET_ABI=armeabi ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags
```

after that

```
make dep && make
```

it will create library for armeabi architecture.Then run command..

```
 $ cd /path/to/your/pjsip/dir
 $ cd pjsip-apps/src/swig
 $ make
```

this will create an android project with armeabi architecture library in

```
  pjsip-apps/src/swig/java
```

folder.Import it in eclipse and  run.You must have to run it in a armeabi supported device.Else above error will occur.